# Old and new values for an attribute in ActiveRecord validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In Ruby, how would I run a validation that says that a model attribute can only be X if it used to be Y? The example would be an attribute `status` that takes either `in-progress` or `complete`. I'd want to say when user marks the object status, it can always be marked `in-progress`, but it can only be marked `complete` if it was first marked `in-progress`.

```
validate :status_change

def status_change
  unless self.status == "complete" && #here i want to say self.status used to be "in progress" 
    errors[:base] << "Can only mark object complete after it was first marked in progress"
  end
end
```

Comment: we can use `before_save` filter for this purpose.

Comment: not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please consider use [ActiveModel::Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html)

It provides methods to track these changes.

```
before_update :status_change

def status_change
  unless status == "complete" && status_was == "in-progress" 
    errors[:base] << "Can only mark object complete after it was first marked in progress"
  end
end
```

Also it's not need to use `self.` keyword here.

Comment: Because `validate` is an alias for valid?` and it runs all the validations.
Author asked about changing model's status (I assume that an `update` action)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [change tracking](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) provided by rails for this. In particular `status_was` returns the previous value of status. You can also use `status_changed` to know where the status has been changed (or else you would prevent other changes to complete models)

Personally I don't massively like the idea of validations that depend on other things than the current set of attributes. You may find that using a state machine (for example [aasm](https://github.com/aasm/aasm)) is a better way of enforcing this sort of behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to implement states for the model.
I'd recommend you use [AASM](https://github.com/aasm/aasm) for it.

It's easy to setup, and you can avoid all these callbacks and validations.

Answer (score 0):

you want to mark status `complete` only if it was first marked as `in-progress` then
You can try this solution

```
before_update :status_change

def status_change
   errors[:base] << "Error Message" unless status_was == "in-progress"
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
validates :status, inclusion: { in: %w(complete) }, if: Proc.new { |status| status.changed? && status_was == 'in-progress' }
```

Something like this should help with your question. However I think that you are trying to reinvent the state machine concept, If this is the case then I'd +vote for other people suggesting using [AASM](https://github.com/aasm/aasm) gem